# MacBook Pro: large amount of disk space being used by the system

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-space

I'm a PC user who is helping a friend who has a Mac problem. He has a 2017 MacBook Pro, 15-inch, 10.13.6, 1 TB.  The problem is that he only has about 2 GB disk space remaining.

Using *About This Mac > Storage > Manage...*, the following is reported, in GB:
Applications:     6.72
Documents:   440.03
iCloud Drive:     4.59
iTunes:           114.75
Mail:                  2.78
System:          **425.56**

I'm surprised at the large amount of space used by the system.  I'd like to review that folder, but it is greyed out in Finder.

How can I make sense of the large amount of disk space used by the system?

EDIT: `tmutil listlocalsnapshots` returns nothing, so this does not appear to be a Time Machine issue.

Comment: I would open a new finder window, hit cmd+shift+. and then get info on the folders which are shown when you open Macintosh HD in Finder. From there you can try to pinpoint which folder is the problem. Tip: if you select multiple folders at once you see how much space they need, so you dont have to get info on every single one.

Comment: Which folder is greyed out in the Finder? I wouldn't worry about /System, which is just the installed OS: but /Library are hidden folder like /var and /tmp may be woth checking. I'd certainly do a restart, as that may free things up. But as said: use something like OmniDiskSweeper (if you've got room to download it!) to sort the disk by size and see what's eating all that space.